# Managing routing with react-router-redux: empty line on top of the list after route change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-redux, redux-observable

I managed somehow to programmatically change route when I receive a 201 from the previous action (post creation).

However, I have a glitch that I can't fix.

When it programmatically gets back to the index, it shows an empty row on top of all the others (coming from the first state which is {}?).

I can't understand why it renders correctly if I access the index directly and it shows an empty line on top when programmatically going there...

EDIT:
I solved the issue above, however I need to figure out with this solution how to replace window.location.replace with react methods as history.push does not do the trick for me.

--------posts_new.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Field, reduxForm }from "redux-form";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {createPost} from "../actions/";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {bindActionCreators, dispatch} from "redux";
import { push } from "react-router-redux";
import PropTypes  from "prop-types";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/dom/ajax";
import "rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest";
import "rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/observable/of";
import "rxjs/add/observable/from";
import "rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise";
import "rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap";
import "rxjs/add/operator/startWith";
import "rxjs/add/operator/filter";
import "rxjs/add/operator/switchMap";
import "rxjs/add/operator/catch";
import "rxjs/add/observable/dom/ajax";
import {store} from "../providers";
class PostsNew extends Component {

    state = {
        theForm: {
            resStatusCode: 0
        }
    }

    renderField = (field) => {
        //instead of using this longer declaration
        // const className = `form-group ${field.meta.touched && field.meta.error ? "has-danger" : ""}`;
        //we can using destructuring
        //this is how it works destructuring on nested objects
        const {meta: {touched, error}} = field;
        const className = `form-group ${touched && error ? "has-danger" : ""}`;

        return (
            <div className={className}>
                <label>{field.label}</label>
                <input 
                    className="form-control"
                    type="text"
                    // onChange = {field.input.onChange}
                    // onFocus = {field.input.onFocus}
                    // onBlur={field.input.onBlur}
                    // etc...
                    // can be condensed as
                    {...field.input}
                />
                <div className="text-help">{field.meta.touched ? field.meta.error : ""}</div>
            </div>
        ); 
    }

    onSubmit = (values) => {
        this.props.createPost(values);
    }

    render () {
        //equivalent to const handleSubmit = this.props.handleSubmit using ES6 destructuring feature
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

        return(
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
                <Field 
                    name="title"
                    label="Title"
                    component={this.renderField}
                />
                <Field
                    name="categories"
                    label="Categories"
                    component={this.renderField}
                />
                <Field
                   name="content"
                   label="Post Content"
                   component={this.renderField}
                />
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <Link to="/" className="btn btn-danger">Cancel</Link>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

const validate =  (values) => {
    const errors = {};
    if (!values.title) {
        // (() => {console.log("test");})();
        errors.title = "Enter a title!";
    }
    if (!values.categories) {
        errors.categories = "Enter some categories";
    }
    if (!values.content) {
        errors.content = "Enter some content please";
    }
    return errors;
};
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    return {
        createPost: (values) => {
          dispatch(createPost(values));
        }
    };
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        resStatusCode: state.theForm && state.theForm.resStatusCode ? state.theForm.resStatusCode : 0
    };
}

export default reduxForm(
    {
        validate,
        form: "PostsNewForm"
    }
)(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostsNew));
```

----- epic_posts.js --------

```
import * as ActionTypes from "../ActionTypes";
import { createPostFulfilled, fetchPostsFulfilled, changeRoute } from "../actions";
import {store} from "../providers";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/dom/ajax";
import "rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest";
import "rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/observable/of";
import "rxjs/add/observable/from";
import "rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap";
import "rxjs/add/operator/startWith";
import "rxjs/add/operator/filter";
import "rxjs/add/operator/switchMap";
import "rxjs/add/operator/catch";
import "rxjs/add/observable/dom/ajax";
const ROOT_URL = "http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api";
const API_KEY = "?key=davide123";

export  const fetchPostsEpic = (action$) => {

    return action$.filter((action$)=> action$.type === ActionTypes.FETCH_POSTS)
        .mergeMap(action$ => {
          return  Observable.ajax.getJSON(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/${API_KEY}`)
                .map(response => fetchPostsFulfilled(response), (err) => {console.log(err);});
        });
};

export  const createPostEpic = (action$, cb) => {
    console.log(action$.cb);
    return action$.filter((action$)=> action$.type === ActionTypes.CREATE_POST)
        .concatMap(action$ => {
                return   Observable.ajax.post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/${API_KEY}`, action$.payload)
                        .map(
                            (data) => {
                                if (data.status === 201) {
                                    console.log("Success status", data.status);
                                    store.dispatch(changeRoute("/"));
                                    // return createPostFulfilled(data.status);
                                }
                                else {console.log("Server error is", data.status);}
                            },
                            (err) => {console.log(err);}
                        );
        });
};
/* eslint-disable */
export const changeRouteEpic = (action$) => {
    return action$.filter((action$)=> action$.type === ActionTypes.CHANGE_ROUTE)
    .mergeMap(action$ => {
        window.location.replace(action$.payload);
    });
};
/* eslint-enable */
```

--- reducer_posts.js -----

```
import * as ActionTypes from "../ActionTypes";


export default function postsReducer(state={}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.FETCH_POSTS_FULFILLED:
            return action.payload.reduce((acc, post) => {
                // console.log(acc);
                acc[post.id] = post;
                return acc;
            }, { ...state });
        // use Object.assign if object-spread
        // syntax isn't supported
        // Object.assign({}, state);
        case ActionTypes.CREATE_POST_FULFILLED:
         const theForm = {resStatusCode: action.payload};
            return {...state, [theForm.resStatusCode]: theForm};   
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Link to the repo I made:
[redux-router-playground](https://github.com/Deviad/redux-router-playground/tree/under_development_v2)

Thank you.

Comment: I did some debuggin meanwhile and the problem could be related with the way how I injected this. Apparently the observable that I create is empty. and this is kind of a code smell. Problem is I cannot use callbacks to pass values as this is not how redux-observable works and I don't know how I can pass an observable at this point that I could subscribe...

Comment: Playing around with the code I managed to solve the issues. However I would like to know how to push the route with react methods. Anyways, I just applied some vanilla redux inside my previous epic. I am going to edit the original post and I am going to make another repo with this updated situation.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is [react-router-redux](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux), which allows you to dispatch redux actions that will change routes in react-router.

Here's an example, but you will probably needs to adjust things for your use case:

```
import { push } from "react-router-redux";

export const createPostEpic = (action$, cb) => {
    return action$.ofType(ActionTypes.CREATE_POST)
        .concatMap(action$ => {
            return Observable.ajax.post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/${API_KEY}`, action$.payload)
                .switchMap(data => {
                    if (data.status === 201) {
                        console.log("Success status", data.status);
                        // We're returning an Observable of two actions, which
                        // will be dispatched by redux-observable in the order
                        // they are provided. The first one react-router-redux
                        // will notice and navigate there correctly
                        return Observable.of(
                            push("/"),
                            createPostFulfilled(data.status)
                        );
                    } else {
                        console.log("Server error is", data.status);
                        // other than the above console.log, this will
                        // swallow the error. You'll probably want to
                        // eventually return an action that can tell
                        // your reducers there was an error like:
                        // return Observable.of(createPostRejected(whatever))
                        return Observable.empty();
                    }
                });
        });
};
```

---

### Edit based on your comments.

You have a bug in your redux store setup. Your `providers.js` and `configureStore.js` file are circular dependencies and in `providers.js` it calls `configureStore()` before it creates and exports the `history` binding.

```
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
import configureStore from "./configureStore";
export const store = configureStore();
export const history = createHistory();
```

So what happens is `routerMiddleware(history)` is basically `routerMiddleware(undefined)` and the error you're receiving is because the router middleware is trying to call `history.push()` when history is undefined.

On a separate note I want to highly discourage importing `store` and `history` like you do in your `epic_posts.js`. The epic is provided an abstracted version of the `store` as the second argument, but I still wouldn't call `store.dispatch` inside your epics as it is a very strong anti-pattern for redux-observable and likely will be removed soon to prevent people from abusing it.

If you find yourself struggling with Rx, [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) is a much easier alternative that may work better for your use case; but only you can make that call of course.

Comment: Hello @jayphelps, I will try your solution, but just so you know that something is definitively weird here are a couple of screenshots: [Chrome Console Log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwCvZShcJFOnRkxJQzZuTl9paVk/view?usp=sharing) and here is [IntelliJ at work with its debugger](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwCvZShcJFOndGRWRXIxNnpUbEk/view?usp=sharing) As you can see two different scenarios. This is the version of the code that I am talking about [github link] (https://github.com/Deviad/redux-router-playground/blob/under_development_v3/src/epics/epic_posts.js)  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, as I imagined there's a problem with the store. Probably it does not get attached to the instance of store or whatever. Otherwise it could be a scope issue... But at this point I am out of clue about how I can fix this.

Comment: I filed a bug report here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5460

Comment: OK, so the discussion has been going on [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5460): basically in the [linked resource](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md) it says I have to send the history object from the component to the epic through the action creator. If I do so, how do I send also the form data as I cannot send complex objects and I cannot even do callbacks? I tried to bypass the problem once with JSON.stringify and it did not do the trick. I hope @jphelps can help with this.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: @jphelps in this branch [v5](https://github.com/Deviad/redux-router-playground/tree/under_development_v5) I applied your suggestions, however the issue did not get solved with this. I applied timdorr indications that basically were to apply this [guide](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md) in particular: "Rather than dispatching actions to navigate you can pass the history object provided to route components to your actions and navigate with it there." Therefore I do not understand why my answer got downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

The following is the answer that I managed to assemble. I used a recursive function to flatten the nested object. It works indeed, however when it goes to the page indicated by the given route at the end of the loading process it throws an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined" which I do not think is related to my code as logging the contents of the observable shows it's all great.

The recursive algorithm does indeed a good job in solving the issue with nested objects.

```
import * as ActionTypes from "../ActionTypes";
import { createPostFulfilled, fetchPosts, fetchPostsFulfilled, fetchPostsWithIdFulfilled, changeRoute } from "../actions";
import {store, history} from "../providers";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/dom/ajax";
import "rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest";
import "rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime";
import { concat as concat$ } from "rxjs/observable/concat";
import { from as from$ } from "rxjs/observable/from";
import { of as of$ } from "rxjs/observable/of";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap";
import "rxjs/add/operator/startWith";
import "rxjs/add/operator/filter";
import "rxjs/add/operator/switchMap";
import "rxjs/add/operator/concatMap";
import "rxjs/add/operator/catch";
import "rxjs/add/observable/dom/ajax";
import {push} from "react-router-redux";
const ROOT_URL = "http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api";
const API_KEY = "key=davide123";

export  const fetchPostsEpic = (action$) => {

    return action$.filter((action$)=> action$.type === ActionTypes.FETCH_POSTS)
        .mergeMap(action$ => {
          return  Observable.ajax.getJSON(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/?${API_KEY}`)
                .map(response => fetchPostsFulfilled(response), (err) => {console.log(err);});
        });
};

export const fetchPostsWithIdEpic = (action$) => {
    return action$.filter((action$)=> action$.type === ActionTypes.FETCH_POSTS_WITH_ID)
    .mergeMap(action$ => {
      return  Observable.ajax.getJSON(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/?${action$.payload}&amp;${API_KEY}`)
            .map(response => fetchPostsWithIdFulfilled(response), (err) => {console.log(err);});
    });
};

export  const createPostEpic = (action$) => {
    const actionVectorizer = ((action$) => {
        if (action$)
        return action$.isArray() ?   [].concat(...action$.mergeMap(x => actionVectorizer(x))) : action$;
    })();
    return action$.filter((action$)=> action$.type === ActionTypes.CREATE_POST)
        .mergeMap(action$ => {
                console.log("action$ is...");
                console.log(action$);
                let { values, history } = action$.payload;
                return   Observable.ajax.post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/?${API_KEY}`, values)
                        .map(
                            (data) => {
                                if (data.status === 201) {
                                    console.log("Success status", data.status);
                                    history.push("/");
                                    // return createPostFulfilled(data.status);
                                }
                                else {console.log("Server error is", data.status);}
                            },
                            (err) => {console.log(err);}
                        );
        });
};
```